Cowboys and Indians TV-series produced in Germany
Possibly made 20-30 years ago, with those now in their late 30's probably watching it when they were children.
It was an American style western but produced in the outback of Germany somewhere.
It was dubbed into many languages throughout Europe. I think I watched it in Slovakia 5 years ago, where repeats would still be shown on Sunday afternoons.
The story had an Indian who befriended some cowboys and helped try to calm the relations between the two camps.
The character "Old man Chatterhan" comes to me, but my searches have led me to nothing, so I'm doubting my memory.

Sounds like you are talking about Winnetou by Karl May. There were several movies and a TV miniseries.
IMDB has a list of all the movies, too.
Oh and, his name is "Old Shatterhand", he is Winnetou's blood brother.

Ah great--No wonder I couldn't track it down!
